# What do you use to browse the Cocoa framework?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm currently using [AppKiDo](http://homepage.mac.com/aglee/downloads), but maybe I'm missing the most common tool to browse the class library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mostly browser the docs from inside Xcode or on developer.apple.com. I never heard of AppKiDo, but it looks pretty nice.

It's hard to beat option-clicking a keyword in the code editor and leaping straight into relevant docs.

Answer (score 1):

Reference doc links:

- [Foundation docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/ObjC_classic/)
- [AppKit docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/ObjC_classic/)
- [Core Foundation docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CoreFoundation_Collection/)
- [Core Graphics docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreGraphicsReferenceCollection/)
- [Core Data docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreData_ObjC/)

The introduction page on some of those, especially Foundation's, have diagrams and contextual information you may find useful.

[This is how I view the docs.](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2009-07-15/my-documentation-viewer) Having set ⌘1, ⌘2, etc. shortcuts for the above links are the handiest part.